# NHibernate rollback does not seem to work

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

My question is simple. I have the below code and user is still inserted. When I check the database just after `SaveOrUpdate` (and before the rollback) I see user is already inserted. It's like flush mode and transaction not working. Where am I going wrong?

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Never;

    using (var tran = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var user = CreateUser();

        session.SaveOrUpdate(user);

        tran.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't claim Rollback to be broken when, according to your description, you haven't actually executed the rollback yet.

Answer (score 1):

If we check **"just after `SaveOrUpdate`"** ... we are still inside of one transaction. Lot of stuff could happen before final decision (commit or rollback).

And one of the operation would be **to decide** if object should be `Created` or `Updated`. So in case, that the ID generator is set to native/identity (e.g. SQL server) - NHibernate must execute the INSERT to get the ID. Lot of operation could be postponed, but to receive the ID - there is no way to wait.

So most likely your ID need to be obtained from DB.. and that's why INSERT happens. **BUT** other stuff won't be written into DB, until `Flush()` is called... So, I wouldn't mark described behaviour as something special.

Comment: It was because my tables were using MyISAM engine which does not support transactions. It turns out I need to use InnoDB engine instead. Anyway, thanks for the help.